# How to get nested json with dynamic value

Tags: json, reactjs

I want to access json with a value in input.

My function and json

```
 import pet3 from '../../utils/pet3' //my json file
 const getValueFromJson = (value) => {

 const data = pet3
 console.log(data.components) //it works fine
 console.log(data.value) // it is undefined              
 }
 getValueFromJson("components")
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the object keys dynamically by using the square brackets:

```js
import pet3 from "../../utils/pet3"; //my json file
const getValueFromJson = (value) => {
  const data = pet3;
  console.log(data[value]);
};
getValueFromJson("components");
```

---

**Edit:**

Alternately, you can install and use a 3rd party library like lodash which provides the [_.get()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) method that can be used like this:

```js
import get from "lodash/get"; // if not installed, run `npm install lodash --save-dev`

const getValueFromJson = (value) => {
  const data = pet3;
  console.log(get(data, value, "default value")); /* returns "default value" if key is undefined. */
};
getValueFromJson("components.filename");
```

Comment: İf the value is like "components.filename",it is undefined.

Comment: You can use lodash's `get` method. Let me know if the updated answer helps

Comment: This answer helped me a lot and also I've found solution in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510640/how-to-get-property-value-from-a-javascript-object