# Accessing a JavaScript object using a string

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a few simple objects defined...

```
var objectOne = {
    settings: {
        name: "object one"
    }
}

var objectTwo = {
    settings: {
        name: "object two"
    }
}
```

Now let's pretend I got `object` from a parameter in the URL - it comes in as a string...

```
var obj = "objectTwo";
```

How can I access `objectTwo.settings` using this `obj` variable?

I can't do the below because `obj` is a string:

```
var settings1 = obj.settings;
var settings2 = [obj].settings; // also doesn't work
```

I tried stripping the quotes without any luck.

How can I access a top level object using a string?

Comment: If it is in the global namespace you could use `window[obj].settings`.

Comment: ^ That's about it. The only other way to access a variable using a string is using `eval` but there's almost never a good reason to do that.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about `window`. Hah. So simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in the global namespace you could use `window[obj].settings`.

If not, I don't think there is much you can do except `eval` as @MikeC mentioned in comments, which is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

`window` is a neat trick, but could you possibly change your data stricture?

```
var objects = {
  objectOne: {
    settings: {
        name: "object one"
    }
  },
  objectTwo: {
    settings: {
        name: "object two"
    }
  }
}

var id = "objectOne";
alert(objects[id].settings.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Let's invent an Object method to access the object properties dynamically. `Object.prototype.getNestedValue()` Regardless how deeply your property is located, it takes a series of arguments in order and gets the desired value for you;

In this particular case it's just one argument;

```js
Object.prototype.getNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 1 ? (this[a[0]] !== void 0 && this[a[0]].getNestedValue(...a.slice(1))) : this[a[0]];
};
var objects = {
  objectOne: {
    settings: {
        name: "object one"
    }
  },
  objectTwo: {
    settings: {
        name: "object two"
    }
  }
},
        obj = "objectTwo";
     result = objects.getNestedValue(obj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

You can see `getNestedValue()` and it's twin `setNestedValue()` working at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37331868/4543207)

Comment: I think you need to make it clearer in your explanation that you've changed the OP's variable definitions to make them properties of a master object.